# UITableView create a badge on the right of every cell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

[image: Example]

I want to create a table view like this one with a badge on the right. Can someone suggest me how can I do to get this result?
thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm using greate open source project **TDBadgedCell** from Tim Davies for that purposes. It is very simple to use and configure.

Get it here: https://github.com/tmdvs/TDBadgedCell

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, this is not available by default. You have to customize your cell.

- Create a `UILabel`.
- Set `textAlignment` as `UITextAlignmentCenter`.
- Change its `cornerRadius`.
- Add a drop shadow using `shadowColor`, `shadowOffset`(a positive offest) ,etc.,
- Set label's `text`.
- Resize label's `width` to fit the `text`.
- Set it as cell's `accessoryView`.

Comment: Since when does UILabel have cornerRadius property? :)

Comment: When you include QuartzCore and use UILabel's layer.